# jQuery datepicker keeps resetting the Hour value

Tags: javascript

I've created 2 `datepickers` and they both work fine, the problem is that they don't keep the `Hour` value, they keep resetting the value to 00:00:00 even If I set a different hour before assigning the `date`. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
 var fromDate = $("#startDate").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
                var instance = $(this).data("datepicker");
                var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
                date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
                date.setHours(23,59,59);
                toDate.datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
            }
        });
        var dStart = new Date();
        dStart.setMonth(dStart.getMonth() - 1);
        fromDate.datepicker("setDate", dStart);

        var toDate = $("#endDate").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1
        });
        var dEnd = new Date();
        dEnd.setHours(23,59,59);
        console.log(dEnd);
        toDate.datepicker("setDate", dEnd);

        console.log(fromDate.datepicker("getDate"));
        console.log(toDate.datepicker("getDate"));
```

The console.log result is the following:

```
statsHelper.js:36 Fri Mar 18 2016 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
statsHelper.js:37 Thu Feb 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
statsHelper.js:38 Fri Mar 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting the dates to `+1w`, which chooses midnight one week from now as the date.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've just tried to pass the date variables (dStart, dEnd) to the defaultDate but I still get the same result